# Al ingresar a un dominio me redirige a otro sitio

Tags: php, hosting, dns

Hola tengo un problema con mi sitio y es que es muy frecuente que al ingresar por ejemplo a www.mipagina.mx me rediriga a un sitio extraño el cual siempre es el mismo: ww7.mipagina.mx como ven es muy parecido salvo el 7, ya hable a godaddy y ellos me dijieron que se veia perfecto el sitio al momento de visitarlo, supuestamente checaron su configuracion y esta correcta, me dijieron que probablemente sea un error de programacion mio, pero lo que no toman en cuenta es que yo tengo un dominio aparte de pruebas con otro host en el cual he subido los mismos archivos php y jamas se ha caido, ahora bien el sitio que he subi en goddaddy lo he subido en una subcarpeta(debajo de un sitio quien desconozco su autor) asi que si hubiera un error en la programacion de esa persona desconozco por donde empezar. Les dejo la imagen del directorio que me aparece en lugar de la pagina. Por cierto la cuenta godaddy no es mia, y el dominio me dijieron no lo consiguieron con goddady.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Hiciste una migración reciente de hosting? Los DNS de tu dominio están bien configurados o están apuntando a otro hosting? ¿Revisaste el `.htaccess`, que no haya ninguna redirección allí dentro (ten cuidado al manipular ese archivo). ¿Te ocurre con cualquier URL del sitio o sólo en algunas URLs? Ese tipo de páginas suele aparecer cuando el dominio no está bien configurado en el hosting actual, o cuando está apuntando para otro sitio, o cuando el dominio está `parked` o algo así.

Comment: intenta hacer un   `tracert tuservidor.com` verifica la ip que te esta devolviendo, si no te resuelve la ip tienes que hablar con el que comprastes el dominio, si te resuelve la que es debes verificar apache

Comment: aveces se demora en replicar a los demas servidores hasta 48 horas

Comment: Solo me occurre con esa url en godaddy